# Javascript Tooltip getting stuck on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am using JQuery tooltip. It is working well with Chrome but when I open page with Firefox or IE and if I click on the link button showing tooltip, the tooltip does not get hide. It get stick there.

This is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#info img[title]").toolTip();
});
```

My HTML:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblOpen" runat="server" CssClass="linkButtonHover linkButton" OnClick="lblOpen_Click" Text="Open"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And in code behind I am assigning value to tooltip from table

The problem is that if it is link and even if we redirect to same page the whole page gets load once again and so the tooltip does not get stick but as I use link button and my part of page gets postback, the tooltip gets stick there. Its frustrating

Comment: if possible make http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Its here http://jsfiddle.net/523Z7/

Comment: it is not working, make a fiddle where I can produce error.

Comment: I am using this code only and it is working for me. Dont know why it is not working here.

Comment: ok try `$("#info").toolTip();` this.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/523Z7/3/

Comment: Still it is getting stick

Comment: Provide full code related to tooltip including HTML.

Comment: I have edited jsFiddle and its on http://jsfiddle.net/523Z7/4/. But as I have used asp:linkbutton it wont work

Answer (score 0):

I got my work done with CSS instead of javascript. http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/.. 
If anybody gets problem like mine use it..